# Is there any limit to the maximum size of a SharePoint Online Document Library?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I need to store 1TB of data in a single SharePoint Document Library in SharePOint Online. IS it possible? Does SharePoint online libraries have any limit in size? What could be repercussion of it. Please highlight?

Comment: Have you even searched Google before asking?

Comment: Yo Danny..I did google it before posting here... All it returned was the max size of file which can be uploaded and that is the common answer I am getting here as well. I m interested in knowing if there is any limit to Document library size. Will be grateful if you can pass the url from google.

Comment: 2 answers below get you links to information on the web. Why did you not find those? I typed this header text of your question in Google and got at least 5 pointers on the first Google page.

Comment: Ok.. I also went through the articles but skipped after reading the article ...my bad I should have gone through the full article....but on positive side this link is appearing in top five links now...life becomes easy when it is stack exchange :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this article](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/SharePoint-Online-and-OneDrive-for-Business-software-boundaries-and-limits-8f34ff47-b749-408b-abc0-b605e1f6d498?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US), 1 TB is the maximum storage size of a site collection in SharePoint Online. So, accordingly you won't be able to upload 1 TB of data in one document library.

IMHO, uploading that much data into single library will also be a design issue depending upon your use-case.

Answer (score 1):

yes.

The default maximum file size is 250 MB. This is a configurable limit that can be increased up to 2 GB (2,047 MB). However, a large volume of very large files can affect farm performance.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx

Comment: I am asking the maximum size of a Doc library. Can it hold 1 TB of data?